# Clear TOP_SECRET_KEY out of bash commands history

Tags: bash, security, tmux, command-history

Working by SSH on remote Ubuntu 18.04 in tmux session with bash I ran command like `TOP_SECRET_KEY=XXXXX app`. Now the top secret key appears in my screen and I guess in ~/.bash_history and maybe somewhere else. What is the proper way to clear it? Is it possible to run command in bash/tmux "privately" i.e. without it being recorded in any kind of "history" files?

Comment: Prefix your command with one space?

Comment: or run it within a script, if space prefix is also logging it

Comment: or `unset HISTFILE` if variable is not set readonly